# Open localhost in a browser referring to another machine

Tags: firefox, remote, remote-desktop

I currently have one service running on localhost on a Centos machine. I cannot change it.

I would like to open Firefox on my local machine in order to open that URL, as the Centos machine does not have user interface and my local machine does.

I tried using this but it didn't work:

```
ssh -Y <user>@<centos_machine> firefox --no-remote

Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

Firefox is installed on the Centos machine.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Firefox didn't start? There is no Firefox installed on the CentOS machine? Firefox did start, but you couldn't use 'http://localhost'? Anything else? Note that when you use `ssh` with X forwarding, Firefox will run on the remote (CentOS) machine, but you'll see the window on your local machine - that's what X forwarding does.

Comment: @dirkt Firefox is installed on the Centos machine, but it does not start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 centos_machine
```

launch your browser on http://localhost:8080

it's pointing to centos_machine:80